# How to properly import scatter_matrix() function from pandas?

Tags: python, plot

It does not see the scatter_matrix, says "not found":

```
import pandas.plotting
scatter_matrix(df[['col1', 'col2']])
```

I tried this:

```
import pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix
ImportError: No module named 'pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix'
```

actually when I hit tab after "plotting." the popup hint for import is showing some functions to import but no scatter_matrix

But doing this works and plots:

```
pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix(df[['col1', 'col2']])
```

Why do i Need the whole path to use scatter_matrix? How to import the scatter_matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change it from

`import pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix`

to

`from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix`

When you're importing you import a file, if you want to import specific function you must specify `from` what file you want to import it (:

Edit:

There are generally two types of import syntax. When you use the first one, you import the resource directly, like this:

```
import abc
abc can be a package or a module.
```

When you use the second syntax, you import the resource from another package or module. Here’s an example:

```
from abc import xyz
```

xyz can be a module, subpackage, or object, such as a class or function.

reference- https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/